# Group multiple result set by count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which loops over some data and returns a count if true. However because of the loop the count only counts that result, so you just get 1,1,1,1 returned etc.. rather than 4.

```
WHILE (@I <= @RowCount)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @forename VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @surname VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT @DOB = forename FROM #mytemp WHERE row  = @I
    SELECT @forename = forename FROM #mytemp WHERE row  = @I + 1
    SELECT @surname = forename FROM #mytemp WHERE row  = @I + 2
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [FPTDB].dbo.clients WHERE forename = @forename AND surname = @surname AND dob = @DOB
    SET @I = @I  + 3
END
```

I presume i need to group the result set somehow to count the results, but i'm not sure how.

Comment: You shouldn't use a loop. SQL is based on set manipulation of data.

Answer (score 0):

You should add another variable and store the sum of every loop count in it.
After the loop you can output the variable value.

```
DECLARE @tot INT unsigned
SELECT @tot = 0

WHILE (@I <= @RowCount)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @forename VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @surname VARCHAR(50)

    SELECT @DOB = forename FROM #mytemp WHERE row  = @I
    SELECT @forename = forename FROM #mytemp WHERE row  = @I + 1
    SELECT @surname = forename FROM #mytemp WHERE row  = @I + 2
        SELECT @tot = @tot + COUNT(*) FROM [FPTDB].dbo.clients WHERE forename = @forename AND surname = @surname AND dob = @DOB
    SET @I = @I  + 3
END

SELECT @tot
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest skip `WHILE` and you can do like this (last select is not tested):

```
DECLARE @mytemp TABLE (forename VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @mytemp SELECT 'tom'
INSERT INTO @mytemp SELECT 'bob'
INSERT INTO @mytemp SELECT 'smith'
INSERT INTO @mytemp SELECT 'mary'
INSERT INTO @mytemp SELECT 'tedy'
INSERT INTO @mytemp SELECT 'carry'
INSERT INTO @mytemp SELECT 'wmary'
INSERT INTO @mytemp SELECT 'wtedy'
INSERT INTO @mytemp SELECT 'wcarry'

--ADD surname, forename and DOB numbering to table (column isType)
;WITH mytemp AS (
    SELECT forename, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY forename) as ID
    FROM @mytemp
)
SELECT forename, 
    CASE 
        WHEN ID % 3 = 0 THEN 3 --surname
        WHEN ID % 3 = 2 THEN 2 --forename
        ELSE 1  -- DOB
    END AS isType
INTO #myTemp2
FROM mytemp
ORDER BY ID


/*result like this
forename    ID  isType
bob         1   1
carry       2   2
mary        3   3
smith       4   1
tedy        5   2
tom         6   3
wcarry      7   1
wmary       8   2
wtedy       9   3
*/



--Join just created table 3 times
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [FPTDB].dbo.clients AS C
INNER JOIN #myTemp2 AS T1 --DOB
    ON T1.forename= C.dob 
    AND T1.isType = 1
INNER JOIN #myTemp2 AS T2 --forename
    ON T2.forename = C.forename
    AND T2.isType = 2
INNER JOIN #myTemp2 AS T3 --surname
    ON T3.forename= C.surname 
    AND T3.isType = 3
```